# In Django 1.10 authentication with allauth, login_required decorator does not work

Tags: python, django

I have just started learning Django 1.10. In doing so, I would like to implement authentication functionality with `all-auth` package and `login_required` decorator.

Here is the snippet code of `urls.py` file I have written.

```
from django.conf import settings 
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib import admin

from profiles import views as profiles_views
from contact import views as contact_views

urlpatterns = [
    ....
    url(r'^profile/$', profiles_views.userProfile, name='profile'),
    url(r'^accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
]
```

This is the code of `views.py` file.

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.shortcuts import render

....
@login_required 
def userProfile(request):
    user = request.user
    context = {'user' : user}
    template = "profile.html"
    return render(request,template,context)
```

Here is the **settings** for `allauth`.

```
LOGIN_URL = 'accounts/login'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'

ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = "username_email"
ACCOUNT_CONFIRM_EMAIL_ON_GET = False
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION_ANONYMOUS_REDIRECT_URL = LOGIN_URL
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION_AUTHENTICATED_REDIRECT_URL = None

ACCOUNT_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION_EXPIRE_DAYS = 3
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = False
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = None
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_SUBJECT_PREFIX = "My subject : "
ACCOUNT_DEFAULT_HTTP_PROTOCOL = "http"

ACCOUNT_LOGOUT_ON_GET = False
ACCOUNT_LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = '/'
ACCOUNT_SIGNUP_FORM_CLASS = None
ACCOUNT_UNIQUE_EMAIL = True
ACCOUNT_USER_MODEL_USERNAME_FIELD = "username"
ACCOUNT_USER_MODEL_EMAIL_FIELD = "email"

ACCOUNT_USERNAME_MIN_LENGTH = 5
ACCOUNT_USERNAME_BLACKLIST = []
ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQUIRED = True
ACCOUNT_PASSWORD_INPUT_RENDER_VALUE = False
ACCOUNT_LOGIN_ON_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION = True
```

As you can see, I use `login_required` decorator to `userProfile` function. So if I go to `localhost/profile` on the browser without **sign in**, the browser should be redirected to `localhost/accounts/login` - to `Login` page.

But whenever I go to `localhost/profile`, the browser redirect to `http://localhost:8000/profile/accounts/login?next=/profile/` and of course I get `Page not found` error.

I would like to know the reason and solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this will help. If it doesn't seeing the traceback of the error might help.

Try changing

```
LOGIN_URL = 'accounts/login'
```

to

```
LOGIN_URL = '/accounts/login/'
```